# my CKEditor load incomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have done all the work to show the CKEditor, but it's incomplete. Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
 <div class="row2">
        <span>Subject</span>
        <textarea class="editor1" id="editor1" name="text"></textarea>        
 </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',[]);
</script>
```

**image of my CKEditor on my localhost**

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn6SL.jpg)

Comment: It looks like it's missing the stylesheet.

Comment: where is the stylesheets files? i just add js file to my project!

Comment: this is my CKEditor folder in my project: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oLDJh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... really strange. Your code is ok, but as @Chris G mention, it looks like is not getting the styles (you don't need to add it, it should take it automatically). Some ideas to test...

1. Are your getting any console error?
2. Try with the CDN version to see if something changes...

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
   ```
3. Could be related to the browser cache. Clean it and reload the page.

Let us know the results

Comment: i find my problem! I've been styling the span tag and the CKEditor was also impressive!